# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: Current thread is not owner of the lock

Tags: java, hazelcast

I upgraded my hazelcast from 2.4 to 3.3, but this exception occurred.

```
13:12:51,269 [Thread-21]: ERROR xx.xx.xxThread:1783 - run:
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: Current thread is not owner of the lock! -> <not-locked>
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.operations.UnlockOperation.ensureUnlocked(UnlockOperation.java:71)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.operations.UnlockOperation.unlock(UnlockOperation.java:65)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.operations.UnlockOperation.run(UnlockOperation.java:57)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationHandler.handle(BasicOperationService.java:699)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationHandler.access$400(BasicOperationService.java:675)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationPacketHandler.handle(BasicOperationService.java:649)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationPacketHandler.handle(BasicOperationService.java:604)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationPacketHandler.access$1400(BasicOperationService.java:591)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$BasicDispatcherImpl.dispatch(BasicOperationService.java:543)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.process(BasicOperationScheduler.java:439)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.doRun(BasicOperationScheduler.java:433)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.run(BasicOperationScheduler.java:408)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponse(BasicInvocationFuture.java:356)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(BasicInvocationFuture.java:289)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:181)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.getSafely(BasicInvocationFuture.java:172)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxySupport.unlock(LockProxySupport.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxy.unlock(LockProxy.java:99)
    at activesync.server.CheckLoginsThread.run(CheckLoginsThread.java:1552)
```

The change for getLock in 3.3 is that the String is required as the parameter in new version. I just changed it from Object to String, nothing else is changed. The code is as below:

```
Map logins = MyHazelcast.getMap("logins");
Lock lock = MyHazelcast.getLock("logins");
lock.lock();
try
{
     // do something...
}
finally
{
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Is this caused by the new version or I missed something?

Comment: I would bet that the problem is the Singleton you're using to wrap the HazelcastClient (this is an assumption). It might help to post the code of MyHazelcast... and to remember that Singletons are evil. Why don't you inject the HazelcastClient inside this class?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it is totally illegible. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
> Current thread is not owner of the lock! -> <not-locked>
```

"not locked" means that lock with given key wasn't found. Is it possible that lock with key "logins" is used in another place?

Maybe you release the lock somewhere inside your code?

I would start with unique key name for this lock.

Comment: I have a map with this key, does it affect?